# Would a use of Backtracking Line Search lead to a higher possibility of overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, overfitting

I've just learnt the method of backtracking line search. As described by [Backtracking line search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_line_search), it is a line search method to determine the maximum amount to move along a given search direction. In this way, would it increase the possibility of overfitting?

Comment: This is just an optimization method! As long as the optimization is carried out to convergence (no "early stopping"), then the results of the estimation method used should not depend on details of optimization algorithms. So the answer is NO.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I see, thank you for the answer.